# Hide DatePicker element only javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik, datepicker

I am used following code hide DataPicker element only hide textbox does not hide image of calender.

HTML Code

```
 @Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model=>model.Dateofpublisher)
```

Jquery

```
 $('[name="Dateofpublisher"]').hide();
```

Comment: could you please share HTML source from your browser for the DatePicker?

Comment: Why dont you use from jqueryui date picker?

Comment: yes used jqueryui data picker

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write DatePickerFor.I always do it as following:

```
<input id="datepicker" name="date*" type="text" value="" />
```

*The name of your datepicker should be the same with the name of your model date filed.
And in script codes just write:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Note:[jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/) files should be added first.

Comment: Maybe the problem is from the loading of your juery files.Are you sure about them and?Are you sure about their discipline?The above code is for mvc.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="Date">
<input id="datepicker" name="date*" type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("Date").hide();
});
```